# Dataframe check next months data and return specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to return the `Bill_Status` for the next month. This information should be validated against two fields: `Cus_Number` and `Cus_Account`

Here is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd  
  
# assign data of lists.  
data = {'Date': ['2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30'],
        'Cus_Number': ['1487', '1487', '1487', '1487', '1278', '1278', '1278', '1278', '1278', '1278', '1278', '1278'],
        'Cus_Account': ['101', '101', '101', '101', '120', '120', '120', '120', '122', '122', '122', '122'],
        'Bill_Status': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
  
# Print the output.  
print(df)
```

For my current attempt I used the following code:

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df['Next_Month']=df['Date']+pd.DateOffset(months=1)
res=df.merge(df,right_on='Date',left_on='Next_Month',how='left')
```

With the following output:
[image]

This is only a small sample however in the main data I have thousands of `Cus_Number` and `Cus_Account` where both of them should be the same and return the `Bill_Status` for the upcoming month. I am struggling to find a solution to validate both `Cus_Number` and `Cus_Account` and return the `Bill_Status` for the next month. any assistance will be appreciated.

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Date` column is in chronological order, so that each next row (per `Cus_Number` & `Cus_Account` combination) contains the next month, try this:

```
df['Bill_Status_Next_Month'] = df.groupby(['Cus_Number','Cus_Account'])\
    ['Bill_Status'].shift(-1)

print(df)

         Date Cus_Number Cus_Account  Bill_Status  Bill_Status_Next_Month
0  2022-01-31       1487         101            0                     0.0
1  2022-02-28       1487         101            0                     0.0
2  2022-03-31       1487         101            0                     1.0
3  2022-04-30       1487         101            1                     NaN
4  2022-01-31       1278         120            0                     1.0
5  2022-02-28       1278         120            1                     0.0
6  2022-03-31       1278         120            0                     0.0
7  2022-04-30       1278         120            0                     NaN
```

Chain `.fillna(0)` if you want zeros also for the last month for each group (though, the next month's bill of course does not yet exist for these).

Comment: If so, then the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73635852/18470692) contains several unnecessary steps.

Comment: They are not unnecessary if you want to have fault tolerant coding. They ensure that no matter how the data is structured that the results of the shift will be accurate. I do not take users at their word that there data is exactly as they posted in the OP, even as the OP stated this is only a sample so ensuring fault tolerance is key to creating as accurate a result as possible.

Comment: I consider it to be the OP's responsibility to supply a sample that is an accurate reflection of actual data. S/he could easily have supplied it unsorted. Even so, I agree that the Q leaves some reason to doubt whether all potential pitfalls have been considered. For that reason, I introduce my A with an assumption on the issue (and add that `fillna(0)` is perhaps odd from a logical point of view). Finally, I write "if so". *If* my answer "works as expected", *then* some of your code is superfluous. Again, I take it to be the OP's responsibility to make sure that his/her claim is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your code and unless I miss the intent I do not believe you would want to shift your Bill_Status_Next_Month based on a different customers Bill_Status. I addressed this by using a `groupby()` and `shift()` so your Bill_Status_Next_Month will only shift for the specified customer/account grouping. If this is not what your intent is please let me know and I can update the code. I also went ahead and filled what would be N/A with 0

```
data = {'Date': ['2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30'],
        'Cus_Number': ['1487', '1487', '1487', '1487', '1278', '1278', '1278', '1278'],
        'Cus_Account': ['101', '101', '101', '101', '120', '120', '120', '120'],
        'Bill_Status': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
  
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['Bill_Status_Next_Month'] = df.sort_values(['Date', 'Cus_Number', 'Cus_Account']).groupby(['Cus_Number', 'Cus_Account'])['Bill_Status'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
df
```